# How do I access program arguments in Swift?

Tags: swift, command-line, command-line-arguments

C and derivatives have `argc` and `argv` (and `envp`) parameters to their entry point functions, but Swift doesn't have one proper: top-level code is just code and it doesn't have parameters.

How can one access the equivalent of `argc` and `argv` in a Swift program?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Process** was just renamed into **CommandLine** (since Swift 3.0 August 4 snapshot)

```
let arguments = CommandLine.arguments
```

(for some reason this wasn't mentioned on the [changelog](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-08-04-a/CHANGELOG.md))

Comment: This is the correct answer now with Xcode 8 Beta 6. This one among many changes I note here:
http://www.brightdigit.com/blog/16/08/17/updating-for-xcode-8-beta-6/

Answer (score 39):

`Process.arguments` is your friend!

Fortunately this is much easier, and built in: no importing anything, no getting your hands dirty with C, objective or otherwise.

Consider this, let's call it `args.swift`:

**Swift 2** version:

```
var c = 0;
for arg in Process.arguments {
    println("argument \(c) is: \(arg)")
    c++
}
```

**Swift 3** version:

```
var c = 0;
for arg in CommandLine.arguments {
    print("argument \(c) is: \(arg)")
    c += 1
}
```

We can compile and run it like this:

```
$ swift -o args args.swift && ./args fee fi fo fum
argument 0 is: ./args
argument 1 is: fee
argument 2 is: fi
argument 3 is: fo
argument 4 is: fum
```

Note that the first argument is the program name, as you might expect.

It seems every argument is a String, as you might also expect.

I hope very much that `Process` becomes more useful as Swift matures, but right now it seems to only give you the arguments.  Which is a lot, if you're trying to write a pure-Swift program.

Comment: You can also use `swift -i` to run Swift code like a Python or Ruby script; along with `Process.arguments` Swift makes for a [promising scripting language](http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/?p=336).

Comment: Is there any documentation for `Process`?

Comment: Ditto above comment - where can I find info on Process?

Comment: `Process` is (finally) documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Process_Enumeration/

Comment: Typo error ? `swiftc -o args...` instead of `swift -o args ...` ?

Answer (score 13):

As soon as your app is up I'd use the process info:

```
let args = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments
print(args)
```

Nothing unsafe there, very convenient.

Note that you have to `import Foundation` (or `Cocoa` / `UIKit`).

Comment: Looks like you have to manually put in `import Foundation` for this to work else it will fail with `error: use of unresolved identifier 'NSProcessInfo'`

Comment: You can just import Darwin if you don't want any ObjectiveC code.

Comment: @DavidH don't get you

Comment: @Daij-Djan sorry missed your question - "import Darwin" should import just the C libraries, and thus no ObjectiveC libraries. Then, it should be possible to use "Process" as others have mentioned in other answers.

Comment: NSProcessInfo is objC and in foundation

Answer (score 11):

For **Swift 3** you can use this code:

```
let argc = CommandLine.argc
let argv = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc))
```

which is equivalent of `argc` and `argv` parameters used in Objective-C main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

For older versions of Swift, you can use `Process.argc` and `Process.unsafeArgv` or `C_ARGC` and `C_ARGV`.

You can pass this variables to `UIApplicationMain` function in iOS app:

Swift 3:

```
let argc = CommandLine.argc
let argv = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc))
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

previous Swift versions:

```
UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

or:

```
UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGC, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

Objective-C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: ...or, more simply, [`CommandLine.arguments`](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/580acd9311c56548259e8f40).

Comment: @zneak sure, it's the simplest way, but you can't pass it into `UIApplicationMain` function, you have to use mentioned `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` instead.

Comment: I see. I only do macOS development. On our side, merely having an app delegate will cause the compiler to create a main function that calls NSApplicationMain. I was assuming that something similar happens on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant alternative to [`CommandLine.arguments`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/commandline/2294816-arguments) is the [Swift Argument Parser](https://apple.github.io/swift-argument-parser/documentation/argumentparser/). `ArgumentParser` will do the parsing of the command line arguments for you, mapping the arguments into a `struct`. It provides all the features you’d expect from a command line app including type safe parsing of arguments, automatic help features, short and long options, etc.

Just use the “Swift Package Manager” to add the `ArgumentParser` package to your command line project (e.g., in Xcode’s “File” » “Add Package” command).

Comment: Awesome, just what I was searching for. Thank you!

Comment: ps. when adding \@main as detailed in the "Getting Started with ArgumentParser" tutorial, be careful to rename main.swift and avoid compilation errors as mentioned in the note "The Swift compiler uses either the type marked with \@main or a main.swift file as the entry point for an executable program. You can use either one, but not both — rename your main.swift file to the name of the command when you add \@main. In this case, rename the file to Count.swift.". See https://apple.github.io/swift-argument-parser/documentation/argumentparser/gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

```
     import Foundation


     println(C_ARGC) //CInt    
     println(C_ARGV) // CString
```

As in the above code, you can use C_ARGC to get number of arguments. C_ARGV to get this arguments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Added a extra explanation