# How do you access command line arguments in Swift?

Tags: macos, command-line-arguments, swift

How do you access command line arguments for a command line application in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access program arguments in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009050/how-do-i-access-program-arguments-in-swift)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apple has released the `ArgumentParser` library for doing just this:

> We’re delighted to announce `ArgumentParser`, a new open-source library that makes it straightforward — even enjoyable! — to parse command-line arguments in Swift.
>
> https://swift.org/blog/argument-parser/

---

#### Swift Argument Parser

https://github.com/apple/swift-argument-parser

> Begin by declaring a type that defines the information you need to collect from the command line. Decorate each stored property with one of `ArgumentParser`'s property wrappers, and declare conformance to `ParsableCommand`.
>
> The `ArgumentParser` library parses the command-line arguments, instantiates your command type, and then either executes your custom `run()` method or exits with useful a message.

Answer (score 327):

**Update 01/17/17:** Updated the example for Swift 3. `Process` has been renamed to `CommandLine`.

---

**Update 09/30/2015:** Updated the example to work in Swift 2.

---

It's actually possible to do this without Foundation *or* `C_ARGV` and `C_ARGC`.

The Swift standard library contains a struct `CommandLine` which has a collection of `String`s  called `arguments`. So you could switch on arguments like this:

```
for argument in CommandLine.arguments {
    switch argument {
    case "arg1":
        print("first argument")

    case "arg2":
        print("second argument")

    default:
        print("an argument")
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want an array this construct is quite handy ```let args = [String](Process.arguments)```

Comment: @AlbinStigo Process.arguments is already an array of strings, no need to make a new one.

Comment: As almost always the best answer is not the the accepted one. :)

Comment: `println` has been changed to `print` recently, but indeed this is the best answer.

Comment: If anyone besides me cares, Process is actually an [enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Process_Enumeration/index.html).

Comment: Is `Process.arguments` the same as `NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments`?

Comment: In the most recent Swift snapshots (either the 7/28 snapshot or the 7/29 snapshot), the `Process` object is now known as the `CommandLine` object. This will probably be fully incorporated once Swift 3.0 is officially released.

Comment: Swift 4: `ProcessInfo().arguments`

Comment: This example code makes no sense. 
Accessing CommandLine.arguments gives you an array of string, and the number of arguments is the array.count.  As always, argument 0 is always present and is the name of the app.

Answer (score 67):

In Swift 3 use [`CommandLine`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/commandline) enum instead of `Process`

So:

```
let arguments = CommandLine.arguments
```

Answer (score 46):

Use the top level constants `C_ARGC` and `C_ARGV`.

```
for i in 1..C_ARGC {
    let index = Int(i);

    let arg = String.fromCString(C_ARGV[index])
    switch arg {
    case "this":
        println("this yo");

    case "that":
        println("that yo")

    default:
        println("dunno bro")
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using the range of `1..C_ARGC` because the first element of the `C_ARGV` "array" is the application's path.

The `C_ARGV` variable is not actually an array but is sub-scriptable like an array.

Comment: You can also use NSProcessInfo, just like you do in Objective-C.

Comment: NSProcessInfo requires Foundation.  My answer doesn't require Foundation. Just uses swift lang standard lib.

Comment: `C_ARCG` seems to no longer be supported.

Comment: I can confirm that C_ARG no longer works with the latest version of the tools, XCode Version 7.1 (7B91b).

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'C_ARGC', not supported anymore on Xcode 7.3

Comment: Operator `..` is not defined for ranges, it's either `...` or `..<`

Comment: You can instead use `Process.argc` and `Process.arguments` for this, though it looks like this might be changing to `CommandLine.argc` and `CommandLine.arguments` with the most recent changes to the language.

Comment: Look at @marc adams 's answer below, instead of this one.

Answer (score 14):

Anyone who wants to use the old "getopt" (which is available in Swift) can use this as reference. I made a Swift port of the GNU example in C one can find at:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

with a full description. It's tested and fully functional. It doesn't require Foundation either.

```
var aFlag   = 0
var bFlag   = 0
var cValue  = String()

let pattern = "abc:"
var buffer = Array(pattern.utf8).map { Int8($0) }

while  true {
    let option = Int(getopt(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, buffer))
    if option == -1 {
        break
    }
    switch "\(UnicodeScalar(option))"
    {
    case "a":
        aFlag = 1
        println("Option -a")
    case "b":
        bFlag = 1
        println("Option -b")
    case "c":
        cValue = String.fromCString(optarg)!
        println("Option -c \(cValue)")
    case "?":
        let charOption = "\(UnicodeScalar(Int(optopt)))"
        if charOption == "c" {
            println("Option '\(charOption)' requires an argument.")
        } else {
            println("Unknown option '\(charOption)'.")
        }
        exit(1)
    default:
        abort()
    }
}
println("aflag ='\(aFlag)', bflag = '\(bFlag)' cvalue = '\(cValue)'")

for index in optind..<C_ARGC {
    println("Non-option argument '\(String.fromCString(C_ARGV[Int(index)])!)'")
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You could create an argument parser by using the `CommandLine.arguments` Array and add any logic you like.

You can test it. Create a file `arguments.swift`

```swift
//Remember the first argument is the name of the executable
print("you passed \(CommandLine.arguments.count - 1) argument(s)")
print("And they are")
for argument in CommandLine.arguments {
    print(argument)
}
```

compile it and run it:

```sh
$ swiftc arguments.swift
$ ./arguments argument1 argument2 argument3
```

The issue with you building your own argument parser is taking into account all the command-line argument conventions. I would recommend using an existing Argument Parser.

You could use:

- Vapor's Console module
- TSCUtility Argument Parser used by the Swift Package manager
- The Swift Argument Parser open-sourced by Apple

I've written about how to build command-line tools on all three. You should check them out and decide what style suits you best.

If you are interested here are the links:

- [Building a CLI tool using Swift and Vapor's Console module](https://rderik.com/blog/building-a-cli-tool-using-swift-and-vapor-s-console-module/)
- [Command-line argument parsing using Swift Package Manager's TSCUtility module](https://rderik.com/blog/command-line-argument-parsing-using-swift-package-manager-s/)
- [Understanding the Swift Argument Parser and working with STDIN](https://rderik.com/blog/understanding-the-swift-argument-parser-and-working-with-stdin/)