# How can I use getopt with command line arguments in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, command-line, swift3

I'm trying to use getopt with command line arguments in Swift 3. I have from [Michele Dall'Agata's nice stackoverflow contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27108932/708833):

```
let pattern = "abc:"
var buffer = Array( pattern.utf8 ).map { Int8($0) }
```

When I then use this code:

```
let option = Int( getopt( CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.arguments, buffer ) )
```

I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type
>   'UnsafePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>!'

for CommandLine.arguments, which I am trying to use as `argv`. Does anyone know the proper syntax for the 2nd argument for `getopt`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please copy the actual error.

Comment: That is the error in Xcode exactly as it appears above the CommandLine.arguments.

Comment: Even the `'UnsafePointer?>!'` part?

Comment: I'll triple check when I'm back in front of the console, but I believe yes.

Comment: @Alexander This was a markdown formatting error; I fixed it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Hamish already answered the question and explained how to pass `CommandLine.unsafeArgv` to `getopt()` in Swift (and why).

Here is a complete self-contained example how a typical getopt
loop can be implemented in Swift 3:

```
var aFlag = false
var bFlag = false
var cValue: String?

while case let option = getopt(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, "abc:"), option != -1 {
    switch UnicodeScalar(CUnsignedChar(option)) {
    case "a":
        aFlag = true
    case "b":
        bFlag = true
    case "c":
        cValue = String(cString: optarg)
    default:
        fatalError("Unknown option")
    }
}

print(aFlag, bFlag, cValue ?? "?")
```

Remarks:

- You can pass a Swift string (here: `"abc:"`) directly to a C
  function expecting a (constant) C string, the compiler will automatically
  generate a temporary UTF-8 representation.
- `getopt()` return either `-1` (if the argument list is exhausted) or an `unsigned char` converted to an `int`. Therefore it is safe to
  convert the return value to `CUnsignedChar` (which is `UInt8` in Swift).
- `while` is used (abused?) with pattern matching plus an additional
  boolean condition to implement the typical C pattern

  ```
  while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1) { ... }
  ```

  in Swift.

Answer (score 6):

`CommandLine.arguments` gives you a friendly Swift `[String]` of the arguments passed – however you're looking to send the arguments straight back to C. Therefore you can simply use [`CommandLine.unsafeArgv`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/commandline/2295216-unsafeargv) instead, which will give you the actual raw value of `argv` passed to your program.

```
let option = Int( getopt( CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, buffer ) )
```