# Login a custom app using terminal

Tags: macos

I have an application Test including user authentication screens. I need to run the app from terminal using username and password. If anybody knows, please help me?

Comment: If you are talking about system user's authentication, then [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) is a way to do that.

Comment: Not system authentication, I mean to execute app functions via terminal commands

Comment: Are you talking about command line arguments? like `myprog --dothis` or `myprog --dothat`?

Comment: Yes. I have a Mac Application for ex: My app. 
My app includes some text fields for username and password and a button to validate login in a server. I need to do the same task through terminal commands like Myapp -u username -p Password. (Ex: Python --version)

Comment: You didn't mention programming language of your application. in C language you can use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and then check command line arguments in `argv[n]`.

Comment: A MAC Application run in swift + cocoa

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24029633/2706918) thread will help you further.