# How to I access argv and argc in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm writing a command line app using Swift but I'm not sure how to get access to the arguments passed in. In C/Obj-c it seems relatively painless but if I try:

```
argv[0]
```

I get an error: *Use of unresolved identifier 'argv'*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24009050/1639670

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. The constants `C_ARGC` and `C_ARGV`. They are analogous to the `argc` and `argv` you'd see in a `main()` function.
2. The `CommandLine.arguments` array will contain all of the arguments to the process. (In Swift 2, `CommandLine` was called `Process`)