# How to get the launch arguments while making a command line tool with swift

Tags: swift, command-line-tool

I make a command line tool in xcode5.1.1 with c.But now I want to make one in xcode6 with swift.
I was struck by the new command line tool project with swift!I know there is no `main()` function in swift,but I can't find any way to get the launch arguments.

Is there any way to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the linked question, there’s the answer [How do I access program arguments in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009050/how-do-i-access-program-arguments-in-swift)

```
import Foundation

let args = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments;
println(args);
```

Comment: Thanks!It seems that I should upgrade my searching skill first...