# How to implement main.swift in Xcode 6 iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

in my ios (swift) app, I have created main.swift in which I am setting a global variable against checking an NSDefault to check for ads removed.

then in each viewcontroller, i am first checking against that global variable and removing ads if appropriate before showing the view.

problem is that xcode does not like @UIApplicationMain in AppDelegate.swift because i have a main.swift. If I remove the line @UIApplicationMain the app crashes on launch.

Am I implementing main.swift wrong?

Comment: Please post the contents of your main.swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your main.swift file will need to look something like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// Your initialization code here

UIApplicationMain(C_ARGC, C_ARGV, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))
```

`UIApplicationMain` will start the event loop and prevent the app from exiting.

`C_ARGC` and `C_ARGV` are Swift vars that represent the C parameters that are passed in through main, namely `int argc` and `char *argv[]`.

UPDATE 2016-01-02:
`C_ARGC` and `C_ARGV` have been replaced by `Process.argc` and `Process.unsafeArgv` respectively. [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24021180/305383)]

Answer (score 7):

as of the very good answer to the question [How do I access program arguments in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009050/how-do-i-access-program-arguments-in-swift) from Darrarski...

The Swift 3 syntax would be:

```
//
//  main.swift
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

// very first statement after load.. the current time
let WaysStartTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

// build the parameters for the call to UIApplicationMain()
let argc = CommandLine.argc
let argv = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv).bindMemory(to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self, capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc))

// start the main loop
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

and don't forget to remove the "@UIApplicationMain" from AppDelegate.swift as it would be redundant and causing a compiler error.

Answer (score 5):

Thats how the `main.swift` should look in **Swift 5**

Hardy_Germany's answer gives warning in Xcode 10.2.

```
//
//  main.swift
//  TopLevelCode
//
//  Created by Stoyan Stoyanov on 04/04/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Stoyan Stoyanov. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

also again don't forget to remove the `@UIApplicationMain` tag from your AppDelegate [read more about it here](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=7)

Answer (score 3):

Swift 1.2 format:

`UIApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate))`